# Drawing verticle lines on video frames in vehicle detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I am working on an application of vehicle detection, the purpose is to check if road is congested or not. The solution that came to my mind is to detect the vehicles moving in each direction separately and then apply limit on the number of vehicles in each direction. I have drawn horizontal lines that detect if the car is moving up or moving down. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to draw vertical lines. If I have height and width of a frame, how can we get parallel vertical lines from that information. One solution for horizontal that I got from somewhere is;

```
# Upper/Lower Lines
line_up = int(2*(h/6))
line_down = int(3*(h/5))

up_limit = int(1*(h/6))
down_limit = int(4*(h/5))

print("Blue line y:", str(line_down))
print("Red line y:", str(line_up))
line_down_color = (255,0,0)
line_up_color = (0,0,255)
pt1 = [0, line_down]
pt2 = [w, line_down]
pts_L1 = np.array([pt1,pt2], np.int32)
pts_L1 = pts_L1.reshape((-1,1,2))
pt3 = [0, line_up]
pt4 = [w, line_up]
pts_L2 = np.array([pt3,pt4], np.int32)
pts_L2 = pts_L2.reshape((-1,1,2))

pt5 = [0, up_limit]
pt6 = [w, up_limit]
pts_L3 = np.array([pt5,pt6], np.int32)
pts_L3 = pts_L3.reshape((-1,1,2))
pt7 = [0, down_limit]
pt8 = [w, down_limit]
pts_L4 = np.array([pt7,pt8], np.int32)
pts_L4 = pts_L4.reshape((-1,1,2))
```

I tried to change, variables for vertical lines, like h to w. But I am not getting the desired functionality. Any help in this regard would really be appreciated. I also want to know how ;

```
line_up = int(2*(h/6))
line_down = int(3*(h/5))

up_limit = int(1*(h/6))
down_limit = int(4*(h/5))
```

this upper code is helping to get expected horizontal lines.

Comment: Have you tried incrementing along x and/or y and just drawing a line with cv2.line(). See https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2

Comment: could you please illustrate the situation and the problem using pictures? your code doesn't do much apart from constructing some arrays whose purpose isn't immediately obvious.